# Custom transparent box with borders only around object

Tags: css

https://i.stack.imgur.com/n3779.png

my current solution has some issues with width, if icon inside box has smaller width then other - it occur box narrowing.

```
table { border-top: 1px double #7F7F7F; }

table td + td { border-left: 1px solid #7F7F7F; }
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, I think you can use flex box model.

https://jsfiddle.net/pablodarde/cyg5sawy/

**HTML**

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <div>Object</div>
    </td>
    <td>
      <div class='forty'>Object</div>
    </td>
    <td>
      <div class='thirty'>Object</div>
    </td>
    <td>
      <div class='twenty'>Object</div>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

**CSS**

```
table { 
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border-top: 1px double #7F7F7F; 
  width: 160px;
}

table tr {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row nowrap;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  width: 100%;
}

table td {
  display: inline-flex;
  width: 80px;
}

table td + td { border-left: 1px solid #7F7F7F; }

div {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  width: 80px;
  height: 80px;
  overflow: hidden;
  background: rgba(255,0,0,.4);
}

.forty {
   width: 40px;
   height: 40px;
 }

.thirty {
   width: 30px;
   height: 30px;
}

.twenty {
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
}
```